# How do I arrange 2 subfigures on top of 1 subfigure?

Tags: floats, subfloats, plot

I'd like the arrange these figures so there are two figures next to each other and one below, like an upside down triangle, so that they all fit on one page and are a reasonable size. How do I do this?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
   \begin{subfigure}[H]{0.75\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{dragratio}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:dragratio} 
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.75\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{dragratio2}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:dragratio2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.75\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{dragratio3}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:dragratio3}
\end{subfigure}
\centering
\caption{(a) Numerical solutions for the constant-curvature body, $F(x)=x(1-x), x \in (0,1)$, at small times. This figure shows the drag force $D$ versus the scaled mass $M$ for various values of the ratio between the inertia $I$ and the mass $M$, i.e. for various values of $R=\frac{I}{M}$. Here $g=10$ and $A=0.7$. (b) As for (a) but with $A=0.5$. (c) As for (a) and (b) but with $A=0.25$.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Do the figures need to be labeled `(a)`, `(b)`, and `(c)`, and do you need to be able to `\ref` the subfigures or only need to `\ref` the complete figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should achieve your goal I think:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
   \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Example-Image}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:dragratio} 
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Example-Image}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:dragratio2}
\end{subfigure}
\\[\baselineskip]
\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.45\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Example-Image}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:dragratio3}
\end{subfigure}
\centering
\caption{(a) Numerical solutions for the constant-curvature body, $F(x)=x(1-x), x \in (0,1)$, at small times. This figure shows the drag force $D$ versus the scaled mass $M$ for various values of the ratio between the inertia $I$ and the mass $M$, i.e. for various values of $R=\frac{I}{M}$. Here $g=10$ and $A=0.7$. (b) As for (a) but with $A=0.5$. (c) As for (a) and (b) but with $A=0.25$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note the size of the `subfigure`s being `0.45\linewidth` to allow some space between them, but then the `width` of the `includegraphics` being the full `\linewidth` within the subfigure, i.e. the full width of the subfigure.